# How to add a column with values using the values of two other lists and another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Original df contains millions of rows. Here's an example:

```
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(
    {'keyword': {0: 756, 1: 756, 2: 13586, 3: 1694, 4: 13586}}
)
df_sample
```

[image]

Now we have two lists:

```
list_a = [756, 13586, 1694]
list_b = [1.44, 4.55, 10]
```

And I need the following output:

[image]

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame(
    {'keyword': {0: 756, 1: 756, 2: 13586, 3: 1694, 4: 13586},
     'Standard_Deviation_keyword': {0: 1.44, 1: 1.44, 2: 4.55, 3: 10, 4: 4.55}}
)
df_output
```

I guess solution would be something like:

```
def key_std(df):

    add a new column = Standard_Deviation_keyword

    for every x value of df.keyword:
      if x == "a value" in list_a:
        find the value at the same index in list_b
        and add that value to the same row in
        Standard_Deviation_keyword column
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` the lists and create a mapping `dict` then use `Series.map` to substitute values

```
df['std'] = df['keyword'].map(dict(zip(list_a, list_b)))
```

---

```
   keyword    std
0      756   1.44
1      756   1.44
2    13586   4.55
3     1694  10.00
4    13586   4.55
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `df.replace` which will not give `NaN` unlike `map` if there is no corresponding elements in the lists:

```
df_sample['std'] = df_sample.keyword.replace(list_a, list_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with a Series:

```
s = pd.Series(list_b, index=list_a)
df_sample['std'] = df_sample['keyword'].map(s)
```

output:

```
   keyword    std
0      756   1.44
1      756   1.44
2    13586   4.55
3     1694  10.00
4    13586   4.55
```